# How to set password for user's github account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-api

I integrated GitHub OAuth to my rails app, user can login my rails app by github account, I don't want to use the the third party gems, like OmniAuth, warden-github and so on.

```
if !authenticated?
  authenticate!
else
  access_token = session[:access_token]
  scopes = []
  begin
    auth_result = RestClient.get('https://api.github.com/user',
                                 {:params => {:access_token => access_token},
                                  :accept => :json})
  rescue => e
    session[:access_token] = nil
    return authenticate!
  end

  auth_result = JSON.parse(auth_result)

  user = User.find_by(github_id: auth_result["id"])
  if not user
    user_attr = {user_name: auth_result["login"],
                 email: auth_result["email"],
                 github_id: auth_result["id"],
                 avatar_url: auth_result["avatar_url"],
                 location: auth_result["location"],
                }
    user = User.create!(user_attr)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  if scopes.include? 'user:email'
    auth_result['private_emails'] =
      JSON.parse(RestClient.get('https://api.github.com/user/emails',
                     {:params => {:access_token => access_token},
                      :accept => :json}))
  end

  redirect_to user_path(user)
```

If user login my app by github account, I will create a user record in database. I have two question:

1. Should I create a user record in database?
2. If I create a user, I have to provide password and password_confirmation, otherwise the validates will failed, how to skip the password validate or generate a random password?

Comment: You can easily skip any validation (if you're the one creating the validation) by making the validation conditional, but I have a feeling you're using Devise.  In which case I suggest 1.) yes, create a new user on successful oath handshake, 2.) redirect the new user to a form to enter any missing information you would like to capture, such as name or password.

Comment: @trh I am not using Devise

Comment: Answer still stands.  Its better to have the user set the password, or set a random password, rather than overriding the validation.

Comment: @trh thanks a lot ! I set a random password, seems work

Comment: why wouldn't you just disable the password validation if the user is coming from oauth?

Comment: @sevenseacat  I can skip the password validation, but it is not a good idea if password is blank

Comment: @pangpang why is it not a good idea?

Comment: @sevenseacat if someone know my github email address, he can login app without password.

Comment: @sevenseacat I have not much web development experience, if you have some good ideas, please tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `SecureRandom` library to generate random string as password.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html